# Merging rows together based on conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset that consists of 5 columns. The first one being the patient, the second and third one being visit times and the fourth and fifth being the status of the patient at each visit. All these columns correspond with each other.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Patient = c('Dave', 'Dave', 'Dave','Dave','Dave','Dave','Dave',   "Angel", "Angel", "Angel",   "Cara", "Cara"),
  V1 = c(1, 150, 240,430,530,650,800,        1, 150, 375,          1, 150),
  V2 = c(150, 240,430,530,650,800,900,       150, 375, 568,       150,375),
  R1 = c("Disease","Disease","Disease","Response","Response","Disease","Response",      "Disease","Response", "Response",    "Disease", "Response"),
  R2 = c("Disease", "Disease", "Response","Response","Disease","Response","Response",   "Response", "Response", "Response",   "Response", "Death"))
```

In this dataset I want to merge the rows that have the same status for each patient until we hit a change in their status. Then once the rows are merged I want to drop them. So I want my final dataset to have all rows where R1 ≠ R2 unless it is the last record. Essentially in terms of a loop (pseudocode)

```
if (r1 =r2 & not last record) { 
record v1 and r1 
walkthrough data until r1=r2 or last record 
record v2 and r2 
print }
```

But the solution does not have to be a loop I am open to other suggestions.

So my final dataset should look something like this:

```
| Patient  | V1  | V2  | R1     | R2
| Dave     |  1  | 430 |disease | response
| Dave     | 430 | 650 |response| disease
| Dave     | 650 | 800 |disease | response
| Dave     | 800 | 900 |response| response
| Angel    |  1  | 568 |disease |response
| Cara     |  1  | 150 |disease | response
| Cara     |  150| 375 |response| death
```

This is what I have tried from a solution from another post but it needs to match the final table exactly .

```
library(tidverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(Patient) %>% 
  mutate(patient_id = row_number()) %>% 
  filter(R1 != R2 | patient_id == max(patient_id)) %>% 
  mutate(V1 = ifelse(patient_id == min(patient_id), 1, V1)) %>%
  ungroup %>% select(-patient_id)
```

I only want to keep the last record if the status is same (r1=r2) depending if the record before has a status change where r1 does not equal r2
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why wouldn't row 11 appear in your final dataset? For Cara, `R1 == Disease` and `R2 == Response`. Could you clarify?

Comment: sorry i was just fixing that mistake as u commented this.

Comment: Thanks! Could you also clarify why `Angel` has an `V2 == 568`? This seems inconsistent with the others

Comment: so I want to combine the visit times together until there is a change in their status. So angel's is 1-568 because he was in the response state until then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |>
  ## pivot the data to 1 time point per row
  pivot_longer(-Patient, names_to = c(".value", "in_out"), names_sep = 1) |>
  ## flag consecutive runs of the same status
  ## and last rows that need keeping
  mutate(
    g = consecutive_id(R),
    keep_last = row_number() == n() & (lag(R, 2) != lag(R, 3)),
    .by = Patient
  ) |>
  ## keep the first row of each consecutive status and 
  ## any last rows that need tkeeping
  filter(row_number() == 1 | keep_last, .by = c(Patient, g)) |>
  ## look ahead to next row to pull the "*2" values
  mutate(
    V1 = V, V2 = lead(V), R1 = R, R2 = lead(R), .by = Patient
  ) |>
  ## drop unused columns
  select(Patient, V1, V2, R1, R2) |>
  ## drop incomplete rows
  filter(!is.na(V2))
# # A tibble: 7 × 5
#   Patient    V1    V2 R1       R2      
#   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>   
# 1 Dave        1   430 Disease  Response
# 2 Dave      430   650 Response Disease 
# 3 Dave      650   800 Disease  Response
# 4 Dave      800   900 Response Response
# 5 Angel       1   150 Disease  Response
# 6 Cara        1   150 Disease  Response
# 7 Cara      150   375 Response Death
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this gives the desired output (ie, there are two records for `Patient == "Angel"` whereas the OP only has one

Comment: Yeah my final dataset cannot contain any rows where r1=r2

Comment: Editing now, should be fixed

Comment: @rstudio_noob unless it is the last row preceded by a row where R1 != R2, correct? (*"...want to keep the last record if the status is same (r1=r2) depending if the record before has a status change where r1 does not equal r2...*). Perhaps if you edit your question to clearly articulate the logic (ie, bullet points), it will help others provide more accurate help (though I'm sure Gregor Thomas will be on the correct solution quickly). Good luck!

Comment: @GregorThomas could you please explain your code to me?

Comment: I added comments, but I think you'll understand much better if you run one line at a time and look at what happens each step.